# Performance impact of updating an index in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I'm working on optimising a database. I'm wondering what the impact is on performance when an update is performed on a non-clustered index column when there are ~9.000.000 records in the table.

I know an update on a clustered index column involves "physical" moving of data. What about a non-clustered one?

I'm looking at an index that is used to seek 68 times but updated 208.000 times at ~9.000.000 records (non-unique). I'm trying to determine the performance tradeoff. Without the index, a full table scan would have been used 68 times instead of the seek (with a runtime of `N = ~9.000.000`). Is this worse than an update being performed on the index 208.000 times?

Thanks

Comment: . . I simply don't understand the question.  The user doesn't "update an index".  Indexes are automatically updated when DML operations are performed.

Comment: I cleared that up. I meant when an update is performed on an index.

Answer (score 1):

There will be some time before the index is created, as a nonclustered index takes its own storage space. It is not as bad as adding/changing the clustered index, which has to re-order and re-write the entire table data.

However, the question isn't so much about the one time which will be needed to create. Instead, you've gotta decide if the extra cost of the server maintaining this index at every insert, update and delete statement is worth the faster queries this index will help provide. If data is read from this table much more often than they are modified, or if there are many/frequent queries that use this index, go on. If nothing of the mentioned facts is true, better not create it.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it appears that the index is write heavy and rarely read, when comparing 208k times against 68 times.

But, can you remove the index? it depends.

- If you have a SLA to return the 68 times data faster always. Then,
  keep the index.
- If you have to make the transaction times lesser for updates, I would
  suggest you to remove the index to make the writes faster and bear
  with the rare instances of slowness due to reading from the table.